# Get current Logged user Wishlist products id in Ajax Call Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, ajax, wishlist, json

I Want currently logged user all wishlist products id's json array via ajax call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this below code in your ajax controller's function :

```
protected $customerSession;
protected $wishlist;
protected $jsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
    $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    ...
}

public function yourFunction(){
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $customer_id = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();
    $product_ids = [];
    foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
        $product_ids[] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    }
    return $resultJson->setData(['product_ids' => $product_ids]);;
}
```

Hope, it maybe helpful for you.

Comment: it returns product_ids json array ?

Comment: Yes. But, not json array. Let me return json array.

Comment: okay its fine , i'll magne it

Comment: Check my updated answer. Now, it will return json array.

Comment: Hai @Rohan Hapani , l'm trying on it

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Wac\ProductListing\Controller\Index\Wishlist\Interceptor

Comment: remove your generated folder : rm -rf generated/* and clean cache : php bin/magento c:c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96479/discussion-between-shafeel-sha-and-rohan-hapani).